# Create Dir with logged-in username

Tags: php, ajax, database, file, upload

i want my script to check if there exists a folder named with current logged in user if he's trying to upload file. the script will check for folder if exists then the file will be uploaded to the folder with username if its doesn't exists the it will make new one and upload the file in it. currently my code is this :

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT user_name FROM upl_users");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['user_name'];
if (!securePage($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) {
    die();
}

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_res) ) {
    $username = $row['user_name'];
    $dir = "uploads/$username/";

    if (!is_dir($dir)) {

        mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
    }

    if (isset($_FILES["FileInput"]) && $_FILES["FileInput"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        // ########### Edit settings ##############
        $UploadDirectory = 'uploads/$username/'; // specify upload directory ends with / (slash)
                                                                   // #########################################

        /*
         * Note : You will run into errors or blank page if "memory_limit" or "upload_max_filesize" is set to low in "php.ini". Open "php.ini" file, and search for "memory_limit" or "upload_max_filesize" limit and set them adequately, also check "post_max_size".
         */

        // check if this is an ajax request
        if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])) {
            die();
        }

        // Is file size is less than allowed size.
        if ($_FILES["FileInput"]["size"] > 5242880) {
            die("File size is too big!");
        }

        // allowed file type Server side check
        switch (strtolower($_FILES['FileInput']['type'])) {
            // allowed file types
            case 'image/png':
            case 'image/gif':
            case 'image/jpeg':
            case 'image/pjpeg':
            case 'text/plain':
            case 'text/html': // html file
            case 'application/x-zip-compressed':
            case 'application/pdf':
            case 'application/msword':
            case 'application/vnd.ms-excel':
            case 'video/mp4':
                break;
            default:
                die('Unsupported File!'); // output error
        }

        $File_Name = strtolower($_FILES['FileInput']['name']);
        $File_Ext = substr($File_Name, strrpos($File_Name, '.')); // get file extention
        $Random_Number = uniqid(); // Random number to be added to name.
        $NewFileName = $Random_Number . $File_Ext; // new file name

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FileInput']['tmp_name'], $UploadDirectory . $NewFileName)) {
            die('Success! File Uploaded.');
        } else {
            die('error uploading File!');
        }
    } else {
        die('Something wrong with upload! Is "upload_max_filesize" set correctly?');
    }
}
```

html :

```
<div id='upload-wrapper'>
<div align='center'>
<h3>Ajax File Uploader</h3>
<form action='upload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='MyUploadForm'>
<input name='FileInput' id='FileInput' type='file' />
<input type='submit'  id='submit-btn' value='Upload' />
<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' id='loading-img' style='display:none;' alt='Please Wait'/>
</form>
<div id='progressbox' ><div id='progressbar'></div ><div id='statustxt'>0%</div></div>
<div id='output'></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there some problem or error you would like help with? Please provide the errors and/or where you are stuck. Code review is off-topic for SO.

Comment: I'm stuck with getting username from database and create a directory with username and upload the file into username folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should use `uniqid()` instead of `rand(0, 9999999999)`. It is both faster and less prone to duplicate results.

Second, you should check if the directory exists before moving the uploaded file:

```
if (!file_exists($UploadedDirectory)) {
    // 0777 makes sure all users can write to the directory
    // true makes sure that any parent directories will be created if they also do not exist
    mkdir('path/to/directory', 0777, true);
}
```

Also in your while loop, you switch to using fetch_array, instead of fetch_assoc:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_res)) { // fetch_array returns an indexed array
    $username=$row['user_name'];
```

Replace:

```
$dir = "uploads/<?php echo $username; ?>/";
```

With:

```
$dir = "uploads/$username/";
```

You don't need to use PHP tags inside of PHP. Remove `$UploadDirectory`, it is a duplicate.

Also, you need to fix your directory checking. Change it from this:

```
if (!is_dir($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
}
```

To this:

```
if (!file_exists($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
}
// Will only reach this conditional if $dir exists, but is not a directory.
else if (!is_dir($dir)) {
    unlink($dir);
    mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
}
```

In a 100% PHP file, remove the `?>` tag, you lose the risk of accidentally having added whitespace included by your PHP.

You need to use MySQLi variables if you are opening a MySQLi connection, not mysql functions:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($localhost, $username, $password, $database);
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT user_name FROM upl_users");

// This will move the internal pointer and skip the first row, we don't want that.
//$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
//echo $row['user_name'];

if (!securePage($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) {
    die();
}

while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    $username = $row['user_name'];
    $dir = "uploads/$username/";
    // ...
}
```

Comment: How do I connect username with mkdir ? ,, I'm using $result = mysql_query("SELECT user_name FROM upl_users"); $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); echo $row['user_name'];   but getting nothing

Comment: You use fetch_assoc at the top, but then you change to using fetch_array in your while. Change it and see if it works.

Comment: Its giving me a  database connection error now but before it was okay

Comment: Where is `$sql_res` defined?

Comment: I think the error is where I'm using $sql_res ,, its the only place where I'm using it

Comment: Use `$result` instead.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/u381071273/public_html/upload/upload.php on line 78 , i think others are resolved now this one is left

Comment: I'm pretty sure that comes from an unclosed brace or parenthesis... I formatted your PHP but I'm still looking for it.

Comment: corrected but im unable to detect the unexpected $end error

Comment: Peer review my edits to your question so that you can look for it as well.

Comment: hey maybe i need to close while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_res)) { // fetch_array returns an indexed array
    $username=$row['user_name']; <--- hereee

Comment: Isn't your code the same as your question? You're closing the brace to your while at the bottom of your PHP file.

Comment: im using notepad++ to check it but its says there is no close for it

Comment: Either copy the code from your question into Notepad++, or your code from Notepad++ to your question, because they're obviously different. (...) And use Notepad2, the superior text editor (this is a suggestion, not a demand).

Comment: latest error omg how many errors : Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/u381071273/public_html/upload/upload.php on line 3 Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/u381071273/public_html/upload/upload.php on line 3 Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u381071273/public_html/upload/upload.php on line 5

Comment: I shouldn't have assumed you were using `mysql_connect` somewhere else... because that's what you need.

Comment: Also consider using PDO instead of mysql functions, they're deprecated: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338

Comment: i have file called db-settings.php, and it contains db conenction code ,

Comment: Then you need a `require('db-settings.php');` at the top of your file.

Comment: added but still same error, checked the db-setting all infos are good , everything if working expect this select from

Comment: And you're sure that you are executing `mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)` or whatever your values are?

Comment: yeah db-settings.php is ok there are register.php , login.php , user,php which connects to the db-settings but only this file is giving me error all others are working fine

Comment: there is functions.php file which connects to the database and gets the pages from db whome are permited to access the database (security reason) i will try to add upload.php to the functions let see if it works

Comment: Add the requires that you have to your question's code. Are you requiring functions.php? Does functions have an encapsulated connection, or is it in a function?

Comment: my fuctions.php is using mysqli and the code above you given me  is mysql , and the code for checking and making directory , it only create the folder and upload a file after that i can't uplaod any file to that folder it says folder already exists

Comment: If you are opening a MySQLi connection, why are you using `mysql_query` and `mysql_fetch_assoc`... ? Use `$mysqli->query()` and `$result->fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: Also, use the if statement in my answer to check if a directory exists, instead of yours.

Comment: mkdir is ok now , can u please type the code for $mysqli->query() and $result->fetch_assoc() as you done before with mysql

Comment: I've added the MySQLi functions. If this works, don't forget to mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: it makes folder named $username not with username from database

Comment: Change the `$dir` declaration to `$dir = "uploads/" . $username . "/";`.

Comment: still same its making folder named : $username

Comment: Put `var_dump($row);` at the beginning of your `while` and make sure that `user_name` is set.

Comment: array(1) { ["user_name"]=> string(5) "admin" } Warning:

Comment: no worries bro everything working fine just took sometime to understand the error ; it was quots error i had to replace `'` with `"` and everything working good thanks to you.